# Why copied objects have the same id as previously copied ones in Python?

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to understand one observation.
I have an application that loads various `Canvas` classes which a user can later work with. These classes are located in several files.
For example.

```
canvas/
    bw.py
    colored.py
    oil.py
```

I import, instantiate and copy these objects like this:

```
canvas_files = os.listdir('images')
imported_canvs = []
    for canv in canvas_files:
        canv = __import__(canv.split('.')[0], fromlist=['Canvas'])
        try:
            new_canv = canv.Canvas()
            new_canv_copy = copy.copy(new_canv)
            imported_canvs.append(new_canv_copy)
        except AttributeError as ex:
             pass
```

Afterwards, a user works with each `Canvas` object from `imported_canvs` list. However, when I import and instantiate these objects twice (run the `for` loop again) I can see `id(new_canv_copy)` is the same as previously imported and instantiated ones.
This would not be a problem unless that each `Canvas` has settings which should be unique for each instance and this is not currently happening. Whenever a user changes the settings in one `Canvas` they are automatically changed in the copied one.

Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example showing the duplicated object?

Comment: I just wanted to know if my logic is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just `copy.copy()` creates a shallow copy. You probably want to use deep copy when copying objects using [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

You can read in detail what's the difference here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

I don't know what `canv.Canvas()` does inside so it's hard to tell what's going on when you run the same code twice when I can't try it by myself.

Comment: Yeah, I know the difference, just could not understand why the ids are the same. Well, with `deepcopy` it kinda works, why kinda, this is a topic for a more comprehensive question.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your note on running the `for` loop several times ad getting the same `id`'s... It might not be the problem with `copy.copy`, as it copies top-level object and `id`'s for top-level mutable objects should differ, but `id`'s for inner mutable objects will stay the same, unlike `copy.deepcopy` where all mutable objects `id`'s should differ.

Probably it's the issue with the `__import__` itself...

When you import a module in Python, it's imported only once. So when you issue the first import of the module 'some_module_a.py' it is imported, and then, when you issue a second import of the same module 'some_module_a.py' it's not imported again, but the reference to the already imported module is reused/returned.

So if you need to re-import the same module more than once, import it for the first time and then use [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) to have it trully imported again.

Answer (score 0):

`copy.copy` performs a shallow copy, meaning any objects will point to existing objects. If you want the objects inside it also to be cloned, you need to use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).